# match multiple column with row value from another frame based on date

Tags: r

I have the below tables:

```
test<- read.table(text = "        var1 var2 var3 var4
                  1 12/12/2017  CAD   10    3
                  2 20/02/2018  CAD   30    8
                  3 14/03/2016  USD   44    9
                  4 10/05/2000  KOR   56   11
                  5 04/04/2016  GBP   45   22")

test2 <- read.table(text = "        date USD CAD KOR GBP
1 12/12/2017   1   2 0.1   2
2 20/02/2018   2   1 0.8   1
3 14/03/2016   3   4 1.0   4
4 10/05/2000   4   5 0.6   5
5 04/04/2016   5   1 1.0   1")
```

I want to multiply the values of `test$var3` and `test$var4` with the corresponding values in the `test2` table depending on the date. So for example if `test$var2` is CAD and `test$var1` is 12/12/2017, it should look into table `test2` to find the spot rate of CAD at that date and multiply it with `test$var3` and `test$var4`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mapply` on `var1` and `var2` of `test` to filter row and column respectively of `test2` to get the spot rate of that particular currency on that particular day. Once we get the `spot_rate` we can multiply it to `var3` and `var4`.

```
spot_rate  = mapply(function(x, y) test2[x == test2$date, y == names(test2)],
                                      test$var1, test$var2)
spot_rate
#[1] 2.0 1.0 3.0 0.6 1.0

test$var3 * spot_rate
#[1]  20.0  30.0 132.0  33.6  45.0

test$var4 * spot_rate
#[1]  6.0  8.0 27.0  6.6 22.0
```

---

We can also get `spot_rate` using `match` which is more or less the same operation.

```
mapply(function(i, j) test2[i, j], match(test$var1, test2$date), 
                                   match(test$var2, names(test2)))

#[1] 2.0 1.0 3.0 0.6 1.0
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, many thanks for taking the time to help! This creates a list column instead of a value, is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: I receive this error when multiplying: Error in test$bvar3 * spot_rate :   non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @AndreasAvgousti What is `class(test$bvar3)`  and `class(spot_rate)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the currency value available in your data.frame without looking you could join the tables together after transforming test2 in long format.

If you just want a lookup Ronak Shah's answer works very good.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test %>% 
  inner_join((test2 %>% gather(key = "currency", value = "curency_value", -date)), by = c("var1" = "date", "var2" = "currency") ) %>% 
  mutate(var3 = var3 * curency_value,
         var4 = var4 * curency_value)

        var1 var2  var3 var4 curency_value
1 12/12/2017  CAD  20.0  6.0           2.0
2 20/02/2018  CAD  30.0  8.0           1.0
3 14/03/2016  USD 132.0 27.0           3.0
4 10/05/2000  KOR  33.6  6.6           0.6
5 04/04/2016  GBP  45.0 22.0           1.0
```